# Ignoring everything but a subfolder in Mercurial

Tags: regex, mercurial

I want to ignore everything **BUT** a subfolder in Mercurial.

The folder I want to keep:

```
a/b/c/d/e/f
```

Everything else under:

```
a/b
```

Should be ignored.

I'm using regexp mode in the .hgignore file. This is what I've so far:

```
a/b/(?!c)
a/b/c/(?!d)
a/b/c/d/(?!e)
a/b/c/d/e/(?!f)
```

Even if this works fine, I would like to shrink it to a single line:

```
a/b/(?!c/d/e/f)
```

Except this doesn't work. I tried to escape the slashes in several ways, but it didn't help.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this:

```
a/b/(?!c).*
```

Comment: This won't ignore a/b/c/doom, for example... :(

Answer (score 1):

You probably know this already, but you can just add the stuff in a/b/c/d/e/f without adding an exception to the .hgignore.  It's not perfect, you have to remember to add any new files, but I thought I'd mention it since it's non-obvious to we CVS/SVN refugees.

Comment: Eheh. Yes, I knew about this but I'd prefer to avoid this habit. It's really error-prone and I usually forget things...

Comment: Fair enough.  You can automate it with something like `hg status -i -n | grep '^/a/b/c/d/e/f' | xargs hg add` which you could even put into a pre-commit hook.

Really though, if you have any control over this project's layout you should probably just move whatever is important and 5 levels deep up to a more top-level directory. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
^a/b/(?!c/d/e/f).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create the hg repo in a/b/c/d/e/f?

Comment: Because a is the main repo, b is an external dependency and a/b/c/d/e/f is a component of b.